# Conditional SQL Statement

Tags: sql, subquery

I would like to ask if it is possible to create a SQL statement with an if or similar structure. 
I have two queries and would like to combine them into one. The only difference between the two is that one has additional AND conditions on its WHERE clause. 
I tried doing a select case, but was not very successful. I will create a parameter "test" that will take 1 or 2, and that condition should determine which query to run.
Here are the queries...

Query 1

```
SELECT ID,AVG(B.VOL) AS PVOL
FROM (SELECT VAR1 AS ID, SUM(VOL) AS PVOL FROM table1 WHERE VAR1='xyz' 
AND DATE_D>'10/28/2013' AND DATE_D<'10/31/2013'
AND CUSTOMER='Market' AND MARKET='South' AND PROJECT=0
GROUP BY VAR1,DATE_D) B GROUP BY ID
```

Query 2

```
SELECT ID,AVG(B.VOL) AS PVOL
FROM (SELECT VAR1 AS ID, SUM(VOL) AS PVOL FROM table1 WHERE VAR1='xyz' 
AND DATE_D>'10/28/2013' AND DATE_D<'10/31/2013'
AND PROJECT=0
GROUP BY VAR1,DATE_D) B GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: What do you want the returned set to be?  You could just use `union all` between them, for instance.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff. I am trying to execute one of the queries based on a parameter that the application will pass. It will be dynamic. So something like...

IF (parameter == 1)
THEN Query1
ELSE Query2
END

Answer (score 1):

You can add the condition based on your parameter @test like below
same query can be used , based on the parameter the condition will be varied.

```
SELECT ID,AVG(B.VOL) AS PVOL
FROM (SELECT VAR1 AS ID, SUM(VOL) AS PVOL FROM table1 WHERE VAR1='xyz' 
AND DATE_D>'10/28/2013' AND DATE_D<'10/31/2013'
AND ( (@test = 1 AND CUSTOMER='Market' AND MARKET='South' AND PROJECT=0 )
      OR ( @test =2 AND PROJECT=0 )
    )
GROUP BY VAR1,DATE_D) B GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: I am using this query inside Tableau, a reporting software. It lets me create parameters and pass its value dynamically to the query. So based on your response...

    SELECT ID,AVG(B.VOL) AS PVOL
    FROM (SELECT VAR1 AS ID, SUM(VOL) AS PVOL FROM table1 WHERE VAR1='xyz' 
    AND DATE_D>'10/28/2013' AND DATE_D<'10/31/2013'
    AND ( (<Parameters.CaseSelector> == 1 AND CUSTOMER='Market'           AND MARKET='South') OR ( <Parameters.CaseSelector> == 0 AND PROJECT=0))
    GROUP BY VAR1,DATE_D) B GROUP BY ID

I get the following error: 

semanticexception [error 10002] invalid column reference

Answer (score 1):

You could create a sproc that accepts the "test" parameter that you hope to build your IF statement around.

```
create procedure --sprocname
(
@test int
)
as 
begin
set nocount on
if 
@test = --bool
select statement 1
else 
select statement 2
end
```

sorry for the poor format I was in a hurry setting it up

Comment: Hi @SFrejofsky, 
I am using this sql statement inside Tableau, a reporting tool, and it does not handle procedures. Thank you for the suggestion though

Comment: I am not familiar with that reporting tool but I would have to assume that it has a sql statement section that you are coding your statements into now. You would create the sproc in sql and then execute it as a sqlstatement.`exec --sprock --parameter` I would assume that reporting program you are using would recognize standard sql syntax